# Get a list of running VMs using VBoxManage

Tags: bash, virtualbox

I want to loop through my running VM's and return only what is between quotes.

So this command:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

returns:

```
"UbuntuServer" {7ef01f8d-a7d5-4405-af42-94d85f999dff}
```

And I only want it to return:

```
UbuntuServer
```

This is what i have so far (fail):

```
#!/bin/bash
for machine in `cat VBoxManage list runningvms`; do
        echo "$machine"
done
exit
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Warning: all of this is is risky if your VM names have shell glob characters in them, or contain spaces.

---

You can do something like this if there is only one running VM:

```
read machine stuff <<< $(VBoxManage list runningvms)
echo "$machine"
```

Alternative with bash arrays (same condition):

```
vbm=($(VBoxManage list runningvms))
echo "${vbm[0]}"
```

If that program returns more than one line, a more classic approach would be:

```
for machine in $(VBoxManage list runningvms|cut -d" " -f 1); do
  echo "$machine"
done
```

Comment: The "classic approach" is bad practice, as is the `array=( $(...) )` approach; both, for example, will replace a single token `*` in your input with a list of files in the current directory. See [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29), and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Need word splitting for this specific example, and VM name matching a glob pattern seems unlikely.

Comment: The worst data loss event I've been present for happened because someone ignored an "impossible" event (a program creating files "couldn't possibly ever" create anything not matching [0-9a-f]{24}; a bug in a 3rd-party library corrupted a pointer, dumping random garbage that happened to include a whitespace-surrounded `*` into the buffer used for a name... and a shell script iterating over filenames to age out of the backup system then deleted *everything*).

Comment: More to the point, practices we teach here are going to be used elsewhere and elsewhen -- unless there's a big disclaimer in the answer, they should be safe to put to wide and general use.

Comment: Alright. I don't have a way to reproduce the output of that command right now, so can't do a "perfect" anwser. Feel free to add your own.

Comment: re: testability -- see the function mocking VBoxManage included in my answer.

Answer (score 18):

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | cut -d '"' -f 2 | while read machine; do
   echo "$machine"
done
```

Comment: That's better than mine - mine will fail if the image name has spaces in it... hadn't thought about that.

Comment: The `while read ... do` syntax is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You could take out the `cut` by writing `while IFS='"' read _ machine _; do`.

Answer (score 2):

for one-liner fans:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | cut -d" " -f 1 | grep -oP "(?<=\").*(?=\")"
```

Answer (score 2):

To validate each line as you read it, the safe way to do this is to write a regular expression and use `BASH_REMATCH` to extract match groups from it.

With the following code:

```
re='^"(.*)" [{]([0-9a-f-]+)[}]$'
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
    name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; uuid=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    echo "Found VM with name $name and uuid $uuid" >&2
  else
    echo "ERROR: Could not parse line: $line" >&2
  fi
done < <(VBoxManage list runningvms)
```

...and the following mock implementation of VBoxManage (to allow folks without VirtualBox to reproduce the test):

```
VBoxManage() { printf '%s\n' '"UbuntuServer" {7ef01f8d-a7d5-4405-af42-94d85f999dff}'; }
```

...output is as follows:

```
Found VM with name UbuntuServer and uuid 7ef01f8d-a7d5-4405-af42-94d85f999dff
```

---

Note advantages of this approach:

- It doesn't make unfounded assumptions, such as excluding virtual machines with whitespace or quote literals in their names from support.
- It detects any line that doesn't match the expected pattern, rather than behaving in an unanticipated way in the presence of such values.
- It still behaves correctly with data that *does* match the pattern but has unanticipated values. (For instance, a virtual machine named `*` won't have that name silently replaced with the name of a file in the current directory).
- It doesn't involve tools external to the shell such as `sed`, `cut`, &c., but relies purely on shell-builtin functionality -- see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) documenting the use of `while read`, and [the bash-hackers' wiki on regular expression matching](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#regular_expression_matching) documenting `[[ $string =~ $re ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | sed 's/"//g;s/ .*//'
```

To loop through:

```
for machine in `VBoxManage list runningvms | sed 's/"//g;s/ .*//'` ; do
    echo $machine
done
```

This will break if your machine has spaces in its name.

Answer (score 1):

`VBoxManage list runningvms|awk -F \{ '{gsub("\"",""); print $1}'`

For each line in the output of `VBoxManage`, this strips out the `"` characters, and then prints the first field (when using `{` as the field separator, which starts the UID of the vbox vm).

There is no need to check for spaces or handle any part of the output differently, or do any shell manipulations other than escaping special characters.

I find [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) to be more versatile than `cut`,`grep`,`sed`, and so on, and it's more expressive too. It's been around since 1987 and a POSIX standard since 1992: you're more likely to have `awk` on your system than `bash`.